# Problem using dynamically added html-object from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with dynamically including an object-tag in my html.
We have a external service which we call to get some html-fragment, it includes an object-tag, a script and a simple html-form. I take that content and add it to a div in my page and then try to execute the script that uses the included object. When i debug using Firebug I can see that the code is correctly inserted in the page but the script gets an error when it tries to access the object. It seems to me that the object isn’t initialized. Let me show you some code to exemplify what I mean.

*getFragment makes an ajax call using jQuery to get the content.*

```
var htmlSnippet = RequestModule.getFragment( dto );
$('#plugin').html( htmlSnippet ).hide();
```

*The included content in plugin-div looks like this*

```
<div id="plugin" style="display: none; ">
    Browser:
    Chrome
    <object name="signer" id="signer" type="application/x-personal-signer2"></object>

<form method="POST" name="signerData" action="#success">
    <input name="nonce" value="ASyhs..." type="hidden">
    <input name="signature" value="" type="hidden">
    <input name="encodedTbs" value="U2l..." type="hidden">
    <input name="provider" value="nexus-personal_4X" type="hidden">

    <input type="submit" onclick="doSign()" value="Sign">
</form>
</div>
```

*The javascript that tries to use the “signer” object looks like this:*

```
function doSign(){
    var signer2 = document.getElementById("signer");

   retVal = signer2.SetParam('TextToBeSigned', 'some value...');

   ... and then some more
}
```

It’s when i call the signer2.SetParam method that I get an error saying

```
Object #<an HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'SetParam'
```

But when I use the original page where the content is loaded when the page loads the script works so I know that the ‘SetParam’ method exists on the object and that the script works. But somehow it doesn’t work when I dynamically add it to the page afterwards.

I’ve Googled this a lot the last couple of days with no luck.
Does anyone have any idea on how to get this to work?

Best regards,
Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Object tag is not fully supported in all browsers [(Source)](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp)
Next, from my experience, jQuery (which heavily relies on `document.createDocumentFragment`) sometimes fails to attach/trigger events on dynamically created/cloned DOM nodes, which could explain why your object failed to initialize.

That said, to try and fix your problem, I suggest using native `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild` methods instead of `jQuery.html`. You can try `document.innerHTML` but if that fails, you can always go with the ones I mentioned earlier.

My suggestion is to either alter your service to replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addElement(parentid, tag, attributes) {
    var el = document.createElement(tag);
    // Add attributes
    if (typeof attributes != 'undefined') {
        for (var a in attributes) {
          el.setAttribute(a, attributes[a]);
        }
    }

    // Append element to parent
    document.getElementById(parentid).appendChild(el);
}
addElement('plugin', 'object', {name:"signer",id:"signer",type:"application/x-personal-signer2"});
</script>
```

OR if you cannot change the content that is returned by the service, run this after you include the content onto your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     * Goes through al the object tags in the element with the containerid id
     * and tries to re-create them using the DOM builtin methods
     */
    function reattachObjectTags(containerid) {
        jQuery('#'+containerid+' object').each(function(){
            var attrs = {}, el = this;
            // We're insterested in preserving all the attributes
            var saved_attrs = {}, attr;
            for(var i=0; i < el.attributes.length; i++) {
                attr = el.attributes.item(i);
                if(attr.specified) {
                    saved_attrs[attr.nodeName]=attr.nodeValue;
                }
            }
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);

            var new_element = document.createElement('object');
            for (var a in saved_attrs) {
                new_element.setAttribute(a,saved_attrs[a]);
            }
            document.getElementById(containerid).appendChild(new_element);
        });
    }

    // Do your stuff
    var htmlSnippet = RequestModule.getFragment( dto ); 
    $('#plugin').html( htmlSnippet ).hide();
    // reattach all the object elements in #plugin
    reattachObjectTags('plugin');
</script>
```

- THIS IS ALL UNTESTED -
  I typed this off the top of my mind, since I don't have the means to fire up IE and test this.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply!
You might be right when you say that jQuery has problems to attach and trigger the events when the object is added afterwards. For now I've solved by including the empty objec-tags when the page first loads and then dynamically add different parameters later on when I know their values and it works. If I get time in the future I will test your proposed soloution.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a test script here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/74874/test_scripts/object.html

If you open up Firebug/Web Inspector, you'll see that the `SetParam` method is in-fact, not defined. I don't know what it's supposed to do, but it's not defined in either case. If you're trying to add `<param>` tags to your embed, you could use the DOM API to do that. There is some code in the test script that does that, but I'll paste it here anyway:

```
var obj_signer = document.getElementById('signer');

var obj_p = document.createElement('param');
    obj_p.id = "myp2"; 
    obj_p.name = "TextToBeSigned";
    obj_p.value = "some value ...";
    obj_p.setAttribute('valueType', 'ref');
obj_signer.appendChild(e);
```

Or be faster using jQuery:

```
$("#signer").append("<param id='myp2' name='TextToBeSigned' value='some value ...' valueType='ref'></param>");
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out but this doesn't solve my problem. I'm actually trying to invoke the SetParam method on the application that the object links to. It should be available and it works if I load the object when the page loads instead of dynamically adding it to the page afterwards. Later on in the script I try to invoke another method by doing signer2.PerformAction('Sign') which doesn't work either.

Comment: @Henrik Is this one of those IE only methods that Firefox supports just because it should for compatibility? I really can't find any documentation on `SetParam` anywhere.

Comment: As I understand it the SetParam method isn't available on the object-tag. It's actually a method that could be invoked on the underlying object itself. A bit like they do on this page when they do mySwf.myFlexFunction(..) http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_5.html

Answer (score 0):

For a jQuery solution, I think this should work:

```
$("input:submit").click(function(){
    $("#signer").append('<param name="TextToBeSigned" value="some value ...">');

    ... and then some more
});
```

Might want to give the submit button a `class` or an `id` and use that as a selector, if you have multiple forms on that page though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but this solution doesn't work either. Please look at my comment on the other answer.